# Type 'BehaviorSubject<false>' is not assignable to type 'BehaviorSubject<boolean>'

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig

I have this in one of my components:

```ts
public booleanSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
```

When I add `"strictFunctionTypes": true` to the `tsconfig.json` file I get the following error:

```shell
× Compiling TypeScript sources through NGC
ERROR: path/to/my/component.component.ts:28:10 - error TS2322: Type 'BehaviorSubject<false>' is not assignable to type 'BehaviorSubject<boolean>'.
  Types of property 'observers' are incompatible.
    Type 'Observer<false>[]' is not assignable to type 'Observer<boolean>[]'.
      Type 'Observer<false>' is not assignable to type 'Observer<boolean>'.
        Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'false'.

28   public booleanSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
```

Does anyone know the reason and how to get it not to throw the error by keeping the `strictFunctionTypes` flag set to `true`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Igor Melo Telheiro** answer is on point. Just to extend it a bit.

You can either declare that field with  `public booleanSubject = new BehaviorSubject(false);`
and it will automatically infer the right type `BehaviorSubject<boolean>`

Or you can declare the field with a type but then the assigned value must be also of that type when declared.
`public booleanSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false)`;

Comment: Although Igor Melo Telheiro's answer is correct and earlier, I mark this one as the solution since it is more complete and points directly to the problem.

Answer (score 17):

Normally when I create a BehaviorSubject I just assign a type to it when initializing it. Try to it like this:

```
public booleanSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
```

Doing so it will initialize the BehaviorSubject type as boolean and I believe the error will go away.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that is that you are assigning the variable `booleanSubject` as a boolean, but the output for `new BehaviorSubject(false)` is of type `false` and not of type `boolean`.

`public booleanSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);`

will output a `BehaviorSubject<boolean>` instead of `BehaviorSubject<false>` and fixing the typescript error.

this usually is because of TSConfig `stict` -> more accurately `strictFunctionTypes: true`